What does equitable mean here?
https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/equality-vs-equity-difference

when opening up a print dictionary, regardless of how thick it is, you’ll have equal access to the pages and the definitions will be written in a manner that is equitable.

Equitable means fair, but what does equitable mean here?

The definitions will be written in a way that is free from 'bias or favoritism'. As it says in the piece that you linked to.

It still means fair. The article is literally all about the meaning of the word, as long as one realizes that "equitable" is derived from "equity." If needed, find the actual dictionary entry of the word. Since the article didn't "work" well to communicate its meaning to you, to make this question answerable, please edit more to explain what about it you don't understand. (E.g., you already know it means "fair." What would make you think it has a different meaning here?)

There's something ironic about asking about how a particular word is used in an article on  a dictionary site and apparently not even looking at that dictionary to say what it says about that word.

I would not have known what the author meant. Equitable normally means "fair to all parties concerned" and I have never seen it used of a definition or the manner in which a definition is written.  I would go as far as to say that it is a malapropism.

@TimR I'd say the main fault is that it tried to (waggishly?) make a point in the final sentence that it hadn't set up and addressed in the article so far, that dictionaries themselves could be inequitable—in the words the include or exclude, in the examples they choose—and of course linguistics can be used as a tool to support inequitable structures (or, I suppose, equitable ones). It was perhaps unwise to try to wedge that in at the end, and the author was obviously reaching awkwardly to make a humorous parallel with the "boxes behind the fence" analogy just mentioned.

@TimR But I'm still surprised that anyone could read through the entire article and "not know what the author meant." It seemed pretty thorough.

@AndyBonner - it is interesting that the linked article is by Merriam-Webster.  This BBC News article tells how a black woman, Kennedy Mitchum, succeeded in getting M-W to alter their definition of the word 'racism'. Just in case it needs saying, I heartily applaud and support what Ms Mitchum did.

@MichaelHarvey And I just learned a bit about the views of its founder, a mixed bag—an abolitionist and white supremacist, and perhaps a theocrat. At any rate, not hesitant to let these views shape his entries.

The OP asks about the meaning of equitable in this sentence:

At least, when opening up a print dictionary, regardless of how thick it is, you’ll have equal access to the pages and the definitions will be written in a manner that is equitable.

This is the final sentence in an article discussing the meanings of two related words, equal and equitable. And it's fair to say that it's hard to see the point of this final sentence. Equitable, for instance, is generally used in relationships between people. We talk of equitable treatment of rich and poor under the law; equitable treatment of different racial and gender groups; and so on. How equitable relates to dictionary definitions is unclear.
Perhaps the key to understanding is the opening phrase, At least. This suggests that the final sentence is to be read in a light-hearted manner: After all the heavy discussion of equal and equitable above, at least we can find one place where these realities take place: in our dictionary!
If we take the sentence seriously, we should not try to redefine the word equitable. It means the same as it has throughout the article. The question then becomes: How is writing a dictionary definition a matter of equity, of fairness? The best we can do here is use our imaginations. Maybe the writer was thinking of a dictionary accessible to all, whether young or old, abled or disabled. Maybe he was thinking of definitions that are free from bias. (For example, how do we define fairly words at the centre of gender wars?) But this is guesswork.

"Maybe he was thinking of definitions that are free from bias. ... But this is guesswork." Really? This seems like the patently obvious reading. Accessibility of the dictionary might be reflected in the "equal access to the pages" bit. For the rest, the author is explicitly talking about the way the definitions are written. I imagine we could find dictionary definitions from past centuries that show bias, even if it's a field that normally tries to stay objective.

The two words in the opening sentence of the article are equity and equality.
